# System.Diagnostics.Tracing with Azure Website

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-debugging, trace

I want to use tracing with Windows Azure but I am having difficulty setting it up to work correctly.

Firstly, I have my `Trace.Write` commands embedded within my code, like this:

```
private static void DefineBallistics(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document document, Motivation motivation)
        {
            Trace.Write("Defining Pdf Motivation ballistics.");

            Section section = document.AddSection();
            section.AddParagraph("Firearm information and ballistics", "Heading1");
            foreach (FileItem fi in motivation.Calibre.FileItems)
            {
                InsertImageOrPdf(document, section, fi);
            }
        }
```

Then, I have application logging enabled on Windows Azure website configuration section as follows:

[image]

So, if I run the code, it seems as if no tracing information is being captured.  In fact, the console window does not display any streaming tracing log information and when I download the log files, there is no application log files contained within the downloaded zip file.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just discovered that the logs stopped working on my site a few weeks ago.

Comment: Frans, I did get it working (can't exactly remember how).  Try using Trace.TraceInformation() in stead of Trace.Write and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Frans - Did this solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `Trace.Write` with `Trace.TraceInformation`, which has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is 6 months later than this question.  I am observing that Trace.WriteLine("Hello trace"); 
 - works with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, but 
 - it does not work with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5.  However, if the debugger is attached, then Trace.WriteLine(string) statements do appear in the Debug output window.  Of course, the Azure Website settings must be set to Application Logging of "Verbose".